# Change event fired instead reset in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to execute my reset event in view through cllection fetch but it doesn't working...

router:

```
var tablesCollection = new TablesCollection();
var tablesView = new TablesView({ collection: tablesCollection});
tablesCollection.fetch({ reset: true });
```

My view:

```
initialize: function(){

  _.bindAll(this);
  this.collection.bind('reset',   this.render);
  this.collection.bind('add',     this.addTable);
  this.collection.bind('change',  this.changeTable);
  this.collection.bind('destroy', this.delTable);
},
render: function() {
  this.el.innerHTML = _.template( this.template, { data : _.groupBy( this.collection.toJSON(), 'status')} );
}
```

Change event is still fired also if I have reset: true in fetch.
I want to render each item from collection through reset event then through change event just edited one.
Thans for any help

Comment: I'm using newest lodash + http://exosjs.com/ ... but I tried newest backbone it is same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting your collection does not remove your event binding. It's just removing the object from the collection.

If another view/server event start to populate your collection again then your view is still binded and still fire events.

First of all I would use .on (backbone event system) instead of .bind

Then if you want to unbind your view from the collection future potential changes use
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off

Or better, if you want to destroy this specific view (and it's still reacting  maybe that's your problem) then use 
http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove

It will automatically unbind all your events.

I hope it helps

edit:

reset will always trigger 'change' cause it changes all the object of your collection. You should adapt your render function to be triggered on 'change' instead of 'reset'.

Comment: Sorry I just want to execute reset event on fetch success

Comment: I wanna render through the reset event each item from collection further from change only changed one... Thanks a lot

Comment: Ah sorry guys I had loaded model before collection.. now it is working properly